# Apply the configuration of the app for each activity

Tags: java, android, configuration, android-activity

How can I apply the configuration chosen by the user, in each activty of the app, without to rewrite the code in each of them?
For example, if I can use the application in fullscreen mode, now I forced to add this code in each activity

```
if(useFullscreen)  
{  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);  
}  
else  
{
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a master activity for your app and add that code to each activity then save the configuration of user. Now you can easily apply the configuration to each page without more LOC.

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/maser-layout-tutorial-reusing-layouts/

look above link to make master page